# Debug Qt project file?

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, qwt

Lets say there is an instruction like:

```
LIBS += -L"../qwt-6.1.2/lib/"
```

in a Qt Project file. Is there some way to check if this path was included in the path to be searched for libs?

I'm stuck in a cross compilation session. I can successfully build the project on Linux (Raspbian) but I can't build the project in Windows (cross). And I think the cross compilation setup is fine because I can build other projects which doesn't depend on Qwt.

Even using the absolute path it doesn't work in the cross environment.

Any ideias?

Not sure if it helps so much but here is the error:

```
c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqwtd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:190: recipe for target 'debug/MyProject' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug/MyProject] Error 1
13:58:40: The process "C:\SysGCC\MinGW32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project MyProject(kit: Qt 4.8.6 (Raspberry))
When executing step "Make"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can! The simplest way is to use something like:

```
message("LIBS contains:")
message($$LIBS)
```

This will generate console output everytime qmake runs.
However, since you just added the path to `LIBS`, I'm afraid that won't solve your problem. (But might come in handy)

Comment: When you use "warning" in stead of "message" the debug info is shown by Qt Creator rather than by qmake